# What are the "balls" that are present in lightning?

Tags: lightning, weather, graph-theory

Whenever I see a slow-motion video of lightning, I see that there are some sort of balls going around before the real discharge.

My question is.. what are those? (Video for reference: https://vimeo.com/133398724)

Also, it seems like if those balls were doing a graph-like search, and when one ball reaches "ground", then it discharges all the energy, I wish to read and understand about that, but I just don't know the term of it so that I can go search.

Comment: i looked at your video and my hunch is that these balls are  charged clouds lit by the lightening- i saw some pictures and cloud origin of lightening.as the phenomena is  associated with thunder storms these balls  move due to storms motion-they are charged and should fall on earth.pl.see the following references;  http://www.universetoday.com/41646/cumulonimbus-cloud/     <https://scied.ucar.edu/webweather/thunderstorms/how-lightning-forms >